# Get browser language from request in Astro

Tags: http, http-headers, astrojs

I've seen you can get http header's info from a request in Astro like this `Astro.request.headers.get('cookie')`. However, I cannot find a way to get the language info from the header in order to return the specific language route. Maybe there's something I'm not understanding. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should be able to use the [`Accept-Language`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language) header: `Astro.request.headers.get('accept-language')`